# How to achieve mouse click in a QDialog while testing?

Tags: qt, automated-tests, qt5, qtest, qt5.12

That's automated testing in Qt.

I've got an table of a class inheriting `QAbstractItemView`, which I get this way from a `QDialog` dialog:

```
    auto *table = window->findChild<QAbstractItemView *>("myTable");
```

I've got a point to click, which proves to be correct, `QPoint clickPosition{x,y};`.
However, the click won't work:

```
    QTest::mouseClick(table, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier,
                       clickPosition);
```

Any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: try with: `QTest::mouseClick(table->viewport(), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier,
                       clickPosition);`, also provide a [mre]

Comment: Thanks, this has solved the problem